# Launching app on boot in android not working on real devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to launch my app on boot, I have searched for hours and written some code. It works on emulators but doesn't work on real devices.
Here is my code:

Inside manifest:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="BootReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

My receiver code:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this change:

```
.equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
```

Comment: R u running on Oreo?

Comment: The emulator it works on, is API 28, the real device it doesn't work on is android 10.

Comment: After Oreo google has made a no of different security policies. One of which is it doesnt allows the device to run background tasks after restarts due to security nd battery optimization. U need to open the app once where u hv written the code logic and then the timer will be again initialized.

Comment: So you mean I have to launch the app manually each time the device boots?

Comment: Also u cant expect the device to auto launch your app. You can do so through some notifi though bt not differetly auto launch.